# jquery json generate html buttons with condition

Tags: jquery, html, json, button

My need is to generate buttons with conditions described in json. Help me please, I’m newbie and I'm stuck. The problem is that my code generates buttons with text "undefined" and nothing happens on button click.

Here is my JSON code (it is valid due to check result at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ , but does not work with html code below):

```
    {
        "Caption": "Module caption",
        "IconsDirectory": "C://Images/",
        "Buttons": [
            {
                "Conditions": [
                    {
                        "ConditionText": "1 == 1",
                        "ButtonText": "Text1",
                        "Visible": true,
                        "Colors": {
                            "FontColor": "#FFFFFF",
                            "BGColor": "#669933"
                        },
                        "BButtonText": {
                            "TText": "Textt1"
                            },
                        "Size": {
                            "Width": 200,
                            "Height": 50
                        },
                        "Icon": {
                            "FileName": "Smile.png",
                            "Width": 16,
                            "Height": 16
                        },
                        "Url": {
                            "UrlAddress": "http://www.google.com",
                            "OpenNewWindow": true
                        },
                        "JavaScriptAction": {
                            "Text": "alert('ok');"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ConditionText": "2 == 2",
                        "ButtonText": "Text2",
                        "Visible": true,
                        "Colors": {
                            "FontColor": "#0FFFFF",
                            "BGColor": "#FF9966"
                        },
                        "BButtonText": {
                            "TText": "Textt1"
                            },
                        "Size": {
                            "Width": 200,
                            "Height": 50
                        },
                        "Icon": {
                            "FileName": "Smile.png",
                            "Width": 16,
                            "Height": 16
                        },
                        "Url": {
                            "UrlAddress": "http://www.google.com",
                            "OpenNewWindow": true
                        },
                        "JavaScriptAction": {
                            "Text": "alert('ok');"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>SMButtons</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
    //When document loaded.
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    // Get data from file as JSON
                $.getJSON('weekendtask.json', function(data) {
            //var buttons = data.Buttons;
               //$.each(buttons, function(key, val)
               //{  
                //$('<li><input type="button" onClick="'+         val.Conditions[0].JavaScriptAction +'" value="'+ val.Conditions[0].ButtonText +'"/>        </li>').appendTo('#ulObj');
                //$('<li><input type="button" value="'+         val.Conditions[1].BButtonText.TText +'"/></li>').appendTo('#ulObj');
    var res=""
    $.each(data.Buttons, function(key, button){
        $.each(button.Conditions,function(key,condition){
        //  console.log(condition)
            res+="<li>"
            res+='<input type="button"' + 
                //'" value="'+ '"Ttt"' +
                '" value="'+ condition.ButtonText +
                //'" value="'+ data.Buttons.Conditions.ButtonText +
                '" onclick="' + condition.JavascriptAction +
                '" style="background-color:'+condition.Colors.BGColor+'         color:'+condition.Colors.FontColor+
                '"/>'
            res+="<\/li><\/br><\/br>test<\/br>"
        })
    })
    $(res).appendTo('#ulObj')

               //});
       });             
         });

    window.onload = function(){ alert("welcome"); }

       </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="silver">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
    <ul id='ulObj'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick` handler should be `condition.JavaScriptAction.Text`. Rest everything was working fine.

```
var res = ""
    $.each(data.Buttons, function(key, button) {
        $.each(button.Conditions, function(key, condition) {
            res += "<li>"
            res += '<input type="button"' + '" value="' + condition.ButtonText + '" onclick="' + condition.JavaScriptAction.Text + '" style="background-color:' + condition.Colors.BGColor + '         color:' + condition.Colors.FontColor + '"/>'
            res += "<\/li><\/br><\/br>test<\/br>"
        })
    })
    $(res).appendTo('#ulObj')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8Ysd/

Comment: Atif Mohammed Ameenuddin, I can't vote yet, but your answer helped me to start with, thanx pal )

Comment: Well, it works at jsfiddle.net, but Chrome returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". What can be wrong?

Comment: on which line? paste that line over here

Comment: Atif Mohammed Ameenuddin, that was extra symbol during copy/paste, never mind. Thanx a lot again!